# Can't make keepAliveTimeout work on Javascript/Express/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, express, http, backend

I have to use a "keepAlive strategy" for a technical challenge. I've been looking for a way to do that.

In this challenge they say that the server will kill connection if it is inactive for five seconds.

I have to made backend and frontend. I have chosen express for the backend.

This is what I have tried:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
    db.sync();
});

//keep alive configuration
server.keepAliveTimeout = 60 * 1000 * 3;
server.headersTimeout = 61 * 1000 * 3;
```

The thing is that it is not working.
[although it shows the timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya2ie.png)
[it gives me error after 5 secs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQXo.png)

I can't find what I am doing wrong
My version of node is 16.14.2

Comment: What are you using to test the backend, and how does that test suggest to you that this approach isnt working? Also I think that `60 * 1000 * 3` is 3 minutes in milliseconds, not 5 seconds

Comment: The company configured the 5 seconds kill connection but I have to use the keep alive to pass the tech interview.
I thought that the error of lost connection was because the keepAlive was not working. 
Maybe I am completely wrong.
What I discovered with the postman is that TCP is 'alive'during the period of time that I  write there. But it stills throw that error if I made a request every 5 seconds.